# kernel assisted function callbacks on memory accesses

Tags: c, ubuntu, kernel, malloc, redhat

I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'm wondering if there is a mechanism, either kernel assisted or just in user-space that would trigger a function callback on a memory access.

I'm thinking something allong the lines of:

```
void callback_function() {}

type *ptr = special_malloc(size, callback_function);

*ptr++; //triggers callback_function
```

If the memory region allocated with the *special malloc* is set, then a memory access would trigger a assigned function callback.

I'm calling it a special malloc, because in addition to allocating memory, I imagine I would need to allocate memory from pages which are somehow configurable to trigger a callback routine during a memory access.

Any ideas?

This would be something similar to a HW watchpoint in GDB, or a segv during an illegal access. I'm wondering if there are ways to achieve this.

Comment: You might be interested in userfaultfd

Comment: Or handling SIGSEGV

Comment: Please tag your OS. My OS does this with a library.

Comment: Just curious, which OS is yours?